# Hide/show specific products for backend users in woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, wp-admin

i have 5 customers who use the same shop in woocommerce. These 5 customers can enter the backend and see there products (but also the products of each other) in the catalog - I want now to hide products for each user which does not belong to his sortiment - Does anyone know how i can achieve this? Plugin or coding, everything is fine for me...

Comment: By _customer_ you don't mean the person buying in the front end but rather _shop-manager_, am I right? So you have one WooCommerce shop and want multiple people to be able to sell products via that, though one person should not see the products of the other person?

Answer (score 0):

Barn2media carries a plugin for protecting specific product categories.  More about that plugin can be seen on their website [here](https://barn2.co.uk/woocommerce-login-plugins/)

When you start looking at pricing products by customer pricing levels there are several plugins out there. WPMayor.com has an article of such plugins that you can visit [here](https://wpmayor.com/top-5-woocommerce-wholesale-plugins/)

I do not endorse any of these plugins, I only know of them having done my own research as I am building a B2B site for my work.

Comment: Barn2media is hiding categories on the frontend not on the backend and the article is quite interesting but there is still no solution mentioned where i can code what i written above

Comment: Sorry, I see what you mean now... All of the customers can go into wp-admin and see each others products.  That does present a unique problem. I was unable to find any plugins that could do that, but did find a conversation on Stack here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35088693/woocommerce-hide-product-data-fieldsbackend